# Print data on table based of another table value MVC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display certain data in a Table based on a on a id- *userDetails.Name*.

This is where I save the certain user data that I want to use in the controller to set the conditions.

```
[Login Controller]
Session["PID"] = userDetails.Name;
```

This is where I want to set the condition, to print out data based on that value.

```
[Data Controller]
public List<ViblyyKeyy> UserGetKeys(string search, string sort, string sortdir, int skip, int pageSize)
        {

            pidusername = (string)Session["PID"];
            using (LoginDataBaseEntities dc = new LoginDataBaseEntities())
            {
                var v = (from a in dc.ViblyyKeyies
                         where 
                                 a.PIDName == pidusername &&
                                 a.Name.Contains(search) ||
                                 a.PIDName.Contains(search) ||
                                 a.Value.Contains(search) ||
                                 a.ExpirationDate.Contains(search) ||
                                 a.Application.Contains(search) ||
                                 a.Type.Contains(search) ||
                                 a.Environment.Contains(search) ||
                                 a.Comments.Contains(search) &&
                                 a.PIDName == pidusername

                         select a
                                );
                int totalRecord = v.Count();
                v = v.OrderBy(sort + " " + sortdir);
                if (pageSize > 0)
                {
                    v = v.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);
                }
                return v.ToList();
            }
        }
```

Action Controller -

```
  public ActionResult UserIndex(int page = 1, string sort = "Id", string sortdir = "desc", string search = "")
        {
            int pageSize = 10;
            int totalRecord = 0;
            if (page < 1) page = 1;
            int skip = (page * pageSize) - pageSize;
            var data = UserGetKeys(search, sort, sortdir, skip, pageSize);
            ViewBag.TotalRows = totalRecord;
            ViewBag.search = search;
            return View(data);
        }
```

Any help on achieving this? thank you.

Comment: `print out data based on that value` what do you mean? You already have the PID on your method, why not just include it in the linq where statement?

Comment: Im new MVC so my syntax knowledge is limited. I had already attempted before like this `pidusername == dc.ViblyyKeyies.PIName`. But doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax should be;

```
var v = (from a in dc.ViblyyKeyies
         where a.PIDName == pidusername);
```

If you want to add it to your existing search, just add a `AND` or `&&` logical operator on the end;

```
var v = (from a in dc.ViblyyKeyies
         where 
            (a.Name.Contains(search) ||
            a.Value.Contains(search) ||
            a.ExpirationDate.Contains(search) ||
            a.Application.Contains(search) ||
            a.Type.Contains(search) ||
            a.Environment.Contains(search) ||
            a.Comments.Contains(search) ||
            a.LastNotifiedDate.Contains(search)) &&
            a.PIDName == pidusername
         select a);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! unfortunately, it is still returning the whole table. I have debugged it and confirmed that the `pidusername` is being passed through successfully. I have added my action call  to the question to see if the problem would lye there. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer, use exactly what i wrote on the query.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. One last question I have another variable in my model `public System.DateTime dateActual { get; set; }` but I didnt know how to implement that in my search. Any suggestions?

Comment: @NoobCoder what I did was I enclosed the `OR` operations in another set of parentheses. This way, logical expression will wait for the output of the parentheses before comparing it with &&. Please mark this as the correct answer if it did. Thanks!

Comment: Marked it correct, and yes I noticed! I had to go in your answer revisions to see the changes. Made sense. Thank you again.

Comment: Oh, for your dateActual property, add a new input field with `type='datetime-local'` or use Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.dateActual, new { @type="datetime-local" }). Then in your code, just add another && operator; If you want a date before the target date; `&& dateActual < a.dateActual`  or if you want a date after the target date;  `&& dateActual > a.dateActual` or if you that exact day `&& a.dateActual == dateActual`